# Solving an infinite geometric series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

> Let $S_k, k=1,2,...,100$, denote the sum of the infinite geometric series whose first term is $\dfrac{k-1}{k!}$ and the common ratio is $\dfrac{1}{k}$. Then the value of $\dfrac{100^2}{100!}+\displaystyle\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\left(k^2-3k+1\right)S_k\right|$ is

**My Attempt:**
$$S_k=\dfrac{\dfrac{k-1}{k!}}{1-\dfrac{1}{k}}=\dfrac{k}{k!}=\dfrac{1}{\left(k-1\right)!}$$
$$\displaystyle\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\left(k^2-3k+1\right)S_k\right|=\displaystyle\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\dfrac{\left(k^2-3k+1\right)}{\left(k-1\right)!}\right|=\displaystyle\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\dfrac{\left(k-1\right)\left(k-2\right)-1}{\left(k-1\right)!}\right|=\displaystyle\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\dfrac{1}{\left(k-3\right)!}-\dfrac{1}{\left(k-1\right)!}\right|$$

Substituting values of $k$ in $\displaystyle\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\dfrac{1}{\left(k-3\right)!}\right|$ gives factorial of negative integers like $\dfrac{1}{(-2)!}$.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You can split the sum.  For instance, when $k=0$, $S_k=0$, so you can start your sun at $k=2$, not $k=1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr but $(-1)!$ is not defined too. We need to start at $k=3$. So, we can manually calculate the summand for $k=2$.

Comment: Can you please show me how to change the starting value of k?

Comment: The formula you got for $S_k$ is not valid for $k=1$. Obviously $S_1=0$, not $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $S_1=0$ and for $k>1$, $$S_k = \frac{k-1}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n}=\frac{k-1}{k!}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{k-1}{k!}\frac{k}{k-1}=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$$

(Notice that this last formula doesn't work for $k=1$, that case need to be treated separately).

Then, as observed in other answers, for $k>2$ we have $k^2-3k+1>0$.
The first two terms of the sum are $\left|(1^2-3\cdot 1+1)\cdot S_1\right|+\left|(2^2-3\cdot 2+1)\cdot S_2\right| = \left|(-1)\cdot 0\right|+\left|(-1)\cdot \frac{1}{(2-1)!}\right| = 1$

Then

\begin{align}
&\frac{100^2}{100!}+\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|(k^2-3k+1)S_k\right|\\ & = \frac{100^2}{100!}+1+\sum^{100}_{k=3}(k^2-3k+1)S_k\\
&=\frac{100^2}{100!}+1+\sum_{k=3}^{100}\frac{(k-1)(k-2)-1}{(k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{100^2}{100!}+1+\sum_{k=3}^{100}\frac{1}{(k-3)!}-\sum_{k=3}^{100}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{100^2}{100!}+1+\sum_{k=0}^{97}\frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=2}^{99}\frac{1}{k!}\\
&=\frac{100^2}{100!}+1+\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{98!}-\frac{1}{99!}\\
&=\frac{100^2}{100!}+3-\frac{99\cdot 100}{100!}-\frac{100}{100!}\\
&=\frac{100^2}{100!}+3-\frac{99\cdot 100 + 100}{100!}\\
&=\frac{100^2}{100!}+3-\frac{100^2}{100!}\\
&=3
\end{align}

Comment: Ah, I missed that the sum is 0 for 1 and got 4. Thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Take out the first two terms as

$$
\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\left(k^2-3k+1\right)S_k\right| = |(1^2 - 3 + 1)S_1| + |(2^2 - 6 + 1)S_2| +  \sum^{100}_{k=3}\left|\left(k^2-3k+1\right)S_k\right|
$$

Now notice that $S_k \ge 0$ for all $k \ge 1$ and for $k \ge 3, k^2 - 3k + 1 > 0$, i.e. the sign will always be positive so you can get rid of the mod notation for $k \ge 3$ and your sum becomes

$$
\sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\left(k^2-3k+1\right)S_k\right| = S_1 + S_2 + \sum^{100}_{k=3}(k^2-3k+1)S_k
$$

If you do the simplifications correctly you should get

$$
\frac{100^2}{100!} + \sum^{100}_{k=1}\left|\left(k^2-3k+1\right)S_k\right| = 4
$$

Comment: The actual answer if $3$ not $4$.

Comment: @jjagmath The answer is given as 4 actually in the book.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha Are you aware that $S_1 = 0$, not $1$?

Comment: @jjagmath Yes its trivial. And it still adds up to $4$ for me !!! Why don't you post your solution and show how it adds up to $3$

Comment: Yes, it is giving 4

Comment: @NilotpalSinha I've posted a detailed answer showing my calculations. I got $3$. I also programmed it and got the same answer in the computer. May be you can also show your calculations to see who has done a mistake?

Comment: @VedaanshAgarwal Are you sure? I've posted a detailed answer. I got $3$.  I also programmed it and got the same answer in the computer.

Comment: @SouparnaPal The book can also be wrong. See my answer for my proof that it's $3$.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha Did you have a chance to check my answer?